# converting text date with am/pm time into 24 hour time in excel non VBA

Tags: excel, datetime

I am looking to convert a text time with a and p on the end into usable time in excel I have used the mid function and I does not seem to recognize the a/p and makes all the times am unless its 12--. Then it will return a PM time. I have used the Mid function and have searched the threads.

Times in the database look like
10/ 1/14  5:14P 
These are text

I have used the mid function
=TIMEVALUE(MID(B6,9,6))
Returning 
5:14:00 AM
when the time should be a Pm or 17:14

Help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: https://ca.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121212180312AAJvs8j might help

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"A", " AM"),"P", " PM")+0`

where A1 has the value.

Format the cell to the kind of date / time / datetime format that you want ; formatting it to :

> dd-mm-yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM

will display :

> 10-01-2014 5:14:00 PM

Comment: Please don't sign your answers.